# Magento 2.2.5 get the product collection without Stock data

Tags: magento2, collection, filter, product-collection, magento-2.2.5

I am using Magento 2.2.5. In that, I am creating the products using the below code.

```
$product = $this->objectManager->create ( 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Product' )->load ( $productId );
$product->setName ( $name );
$product->setDescription ( $description );
$product->setPrice ( $price );
$product->setStatus(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Status::STATUS_DISABLED);
$id = null;
$manager = $this->objectManager->get ( 'Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface' );
$store = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);//$manager->getStore ( $id );
$websiteId = $store->getWebsiteId ();
$product->setWebsiteIds ( array ( $websiteId) );
$product->setStockData ( array ('use_config_manage_stock' => 0,'is_in_stock' => 1,'manage_stock' => 0,'use_config_notify_stock_qty' => 0 ) );
$product->save ();
```

It is saving. When I loading with Block using following code:

```
 protected function _construct() {
    parent::_construct ();
    $collection = $this->getFilterProducts ();
    $this->setCollection ( $collection );
}
public function getFilterProducts() {        
    /**
     * Filter by product attributes
     */
    $product = $this->productFactory->addAttributeToSelect ( '*' )->addAttributeToFilter ( 'user_id', $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId () );
    $product->addAttributeToFilter ( 'visibility', array (
            'eq' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH
    ) );
    $product->addAttributeToSort ( 'entity_id', 'DESC' );

    /**
     * Return product object
     */
    return $product;
}
protected function _prepareLayout() {
    parent::_prepareLayout ();
    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager
     */
    $pager = $this->getLayout ()->createBlock ( 'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager', 'mymodule.product.list.pager' );
    $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(
            10 => 10,
            20 => 20,
            50 => 50
        ))->setShowAmounts ( false )->setCollection ($this->getCollection ());
    $this->setChild ( 'pager', $pager );
    $this->getCollection () ->load();
    return $this;
}

public function getPagerHtml() {
    return $this->getChildHtml ( 'pager' );
}
```

In this block file I am trying to print the product collection, It has all the products with the user_id(custom attribute). But When I am printing the collection in the phtml file as `$this->getCollection()` it has the filter with stock data. But I am not including this stock filter anywhere. Is this Default or How I can get the product collection without Stock data. Please help me to get the product collection.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove stock filter overriding 2 classes from catalog inventory module:

```
  <preference for="Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status" type="Namespace\Catalog_Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status" />
<preference for="Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock" type="NameSpace\Catalog_Inventory\Helper\Stock" />
```

Namespace\Catalog_Inventory\Helper\Stock\Status file like below:

```
                <?php

          namespace Namespace\Catalog_Inventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock;

       use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock;
     use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockConfigurationInterface;
     use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

     class Status extends \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status
        {
/**
 * Store model manager
 *
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 * @deprecated 100.1.0
 */
protected $_storeManager;

/**
 * Website model factory
 *
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory
 */
protected $_websiteFactory;

/**
 * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
 */
protected $eavConfig;

/**
 * @var StockConfigurationInterface
 */
protected  $stockConfiguration;

/**
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
 * @param \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory
 * @param \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
 * @param string $connectionName
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\WebsiteFactory $websiteFactory,
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
     $connectionName = null

) {
    parent::__construct($context,$storeManager,$websiteFactory,$eavConfig,$connectionName);

    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_websiteFactory = $websiteFactory;
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
}

public function addStockDataToCollection($collection, $isFilterInStock)
{
    $manageStock=$this->scopeConfig->getValue('cataloginventory/item_options/manage_stock', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE);
    if($manageStock!=0)
    {
        $websiteId = $this->getStockConfiguration()->getDefaultScopeId();
        $joinCondition = $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
            'e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id' . ' AND stock_status_index.website_id = ?',
            $websiteId
        );

        $joinCondition .= $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
            ' AND stock_status_index.stock_id = ?',
            Stock::DEFAULT_STOCK_ID
        );
        $method = $isFilterInStock ? 'join' : 'joinLeft';
        $collection->getSelect()->$method(
            ['stock_status_index' => $this->getMainTable()],
            $joinCondition,
            ['is_salable' => 'stock_status']
        );

        if ($isFilterInStock) {
            $collection->getSelect()->where(
                'stock_status_index.stock_status = ?',
                Stock\Status::STATUS_IN_STOCK
            );
        }
}
    return $collection;
}

/**
 * @return StockConfigurationInterface
 *
 * @deprecated 100.1.0
 */
protected function getStockConfiguration()
{
    if ($this->stockConfiguration === null) {
        $this->stockConfiguration = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockConfigurationInterface::class);
    }
    return $this->stockConfiguration;
}
```

}

and NameSpace\Catalog_Inventory\Helper\Stock:

```
<?php

 namespace Tatva\Catalog_Inventory\Helper;

 use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockConfigurationInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\Status;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\ResourceModel\Stock\StatusFactory;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Spi\StockRegistryProviderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;


class Stock extends \Magento\CatalogInventory\Helper\Stock
```

{
    /**
     * Store model manager
     *
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

```
/**
 * Core store config
 *
 * @var ScopeConfigInterface
 */
protected $scopeConfig;

/**
 * @var Status
 */
protected $stockStatusResource;

/**
 * @var StatusFactory
 */
protected $stockStatusFactory;

/**
 * @var StockRegistryProviderInterface
 */
private $stockRegistryProvider;


private $stockConfiguration;


public function __construct(
    StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
    StatusFactory $stockStatusFactory,
    StockRegistryProviderInterface $stockRegistryProvider
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    $this->stockStatusFactory  = $stockStatusFactory;
    $this->stockRegistryProvider = $stockRegistryProvider;
    return parent::__construct($storeManager,$scopeConfig,$stockStatusFactory,$stockRegistryProvider);
}

/**
 * Assign stock status information to product
 *
 * @param Product $product
 * @param int $status
 * @return void
 */
public function assignStatusToProduct(Product $product, $status = null)
{
    if ($status === null) {
        $scopeId = $this->getStockConfiguration()->getDefaultScopeId();
        $stockStatus = $this->stockRegistryProvider->getStockStatus($product->getId(), $scopeId);
        $status = $stockStatus->getStockStatus();
    }
    $product->setIsSalable(true);
}
  protected function getStockConfiguration()
{
    if ($this->stockConfiguration === null) {
        $this->stockConfiguration = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockConfigurationInterface::class);
    }
    return $this->stockConfiguration;
}
```

}